# Ballistically sensitive weak points in the modern military and civilian supply and manufacturing chain

Tags: modern-age, military, logistics, manufacturing

This question is part of my series of questions about Jormungandr, the alien Snakebot of Doom.

So far, the SoD has eliminated the majority of the world's land-based nuclear missile forces and the US nuclear manufacturing plants, as well as a good portion of the US' military aviation, artillery and many munitions factories.

With its most significant military threats diminished, the SoD is now ready to move on to making more general attacks towards its ultimate goal of destroying all human infrastructure more complex than a tent or shack.

Its designers intended it to physically roll over the majority of its targets, but its rail-gun capability means that it is actually more efficient to ballistically attack most of its targets .

To that end, as the next task of destruction on its list is to cripple the production of military munitions and vehicles, as well as reducing the ability of humans to build civilian structures, what targets that can be attacked and destroyed by tons of steel shot descending from the sky at several kilometers per second would most effectively cripple the relevant manufacturing capabilities?

Please keep in mind that while power generation facilities may be a tempting option, those are further down the list of targets for the reason that they facilitate electronic communication between humans to which the SoD wants to listen.

Comment: Communications will last for a while on generator backups, at least the military ones. But if you really do not want to go after energy, go after steel manufacturing: it is essential, plants are large, so there are few of them. Also, target transportation: ports and airfields, rail yards, bridges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Germans learned in WW2, you can't do much when the enemy is interdicting your POL (petroleum, oil, lubricants) supply.

First World militaries are even more dependent.  Thus, attack:

1. oil refineries,
2. gas pipeline hubs,
3. tank farms,
4. rail junctions used by coal trains,
5. etc.
6. For the *coup de grace*, blast nuclear power stations.

Comment: Coup de *grâce*? ("Gras" means "fat" in French.)

Comment: What about disrupting the constitution industry? Is POL vital for all construction, industrial as well as civilian? Don't groups like the Amish construct quite elaborate dwellings without POL?

Comment: @MontyWildb sure the Amish build nice, sturdy **wooden barns**, but your question quite specifically mentions "**cripple the production of military munitions and vehicles**", and the Amish don't make many Abrams tanks or Bradley Fighting Vehicles.  Nor the munitions they shoot.  **But you knew that**, right.

Comment: @RonJohn, The question included building houses out of whatever materials that humans might choose, and low-energy methods of construction are still of interest.

Comment: @MontyWild how does the lumber that the Amish use get to the Amish from where the suitable trees grow?  And where does the iron come from for their steel axes and saws?  Now multiply that problem by 1300.  Bottom line: First World societies are extremely #1 energy dependent **and** #2 **trade dependent**.  Of course, trade is powered by energy and transportation too...